# Wordpress image upload from different networks

Tags: php, wordpress, image

Ok folks, having a super weird issue.

A client has has a new wordpress site they put up and we've found an issue:

When on their network, using the media library and uploading images, the images do not make it into the wp-content/uploads folder, however, you can see the images in the library. HOWEVER, if you upload an image from ANYWHERE else, including Starbucks or via Verizon phone hotspot, the images upload as they should and appear as they should.

I thought it might have been a network issue, but the images are getting pushed with no errors, they just do not appear in the uploads folder.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Check the FTP and search for it. It stored somewhere. Do you have any gallery plugins? If so, check the plugin folder.

At times they do go in a subfolders with just dates (e.g. 12122015).

Comment: No plugins attached to this one for this. The images should be going into wp-contents/uploads/2015/10. Like I said, when off the network, they are perfect. When on the network, they don't make it to the folder but still appear in the library.